# angularjs- UI elements (Grid) are not updating even after binded scope variable is updated

Tags: angularjs

My UI is bound to a couple scope variables, which are linked to parameters on an object.

When I update the bound variables in an update() method, my UI grid is not getting updated. The variable has all the required properties and values.

```
  function update() {
        $scope.summaryValuesStruct = service.summaryValuesStruct;
        $scope.aggregateByValue = service.aggregation;
    }
```

After update is called, I was expecting the UI grid would get updated, because the service object puts new value in the variables.

Comment: please provide html also

Comment: Are you sure that the values are updated on your service? Have you tried outputting (console.log) the values for these values and the scope variables when update is called to verify what the values are when the function is called?

Comment: How update function gets called?

Answer (score 0):

While this is missing a lot of information, my guess is that it's because you're using properties directly on the `$scope`. I'm guessing that it's updating a child scope instead of the parent.

Instead try storing your data as an object in the scope.

```
function update() {
        $scope.data.summaryValuesStruct = service.summaryValuesStruct;
        $scope.data.aggregateByValue = service.aggregation;
    }
```

See  [jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html) for a more in depth explanation.

Comment: can you please update little more as why it would update child scope and should we not use property directly on $scope

Comment: It goes to how Javascript handles prototypically inherited objects (which is what scope inheritance is built on). http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html is a better article on it than I could explain here. controllerAs syntax will get you around this issue as well.